# How to put focus to textbox as needed

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, setfocus

I have a textbox on a userform. If the user fails to enter anything in this textbox, I need to trap that to force an entry. I can do this easily enough, but after notifying the user tht they need to make an entry, I want the focus to return to the textbox. Right now, it doesn't do that. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub txtAnswer_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Select Case KeyCode
    Case 13:
        If Me.txtAnswer.Value = "" Then
            temp = MsgBox("You need to enter an answer!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "No Answer Found!")
            Me.txtAnswer.SetFocus
        Else
            recordAnswer
        End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

This code works fine in that the message box pops up if the textbox is left blank. After clearing the message box, if I hit enter immediately again, the message box reappears, suggesting that the focus is on the textbox. However, if I try to enter a character (like the number '1' for example) nothing appears in the textbox.

Can anybody suggest how I can get the focus back on this textbox in a way that will allow the user to enter data?  Thank you!

Comment: It works just fine for me... What does `recordAnswer` do?

Comment: Strange. recordAnswer does a bunch of stuff, mostly it populates data onto a worksheet. That subroutine has been thoroughly field tested, so I know it's not the problem. I guess that I'll just leave it as is. The user will just have to click the textbox to get the focus back there.  Thanks!

Comment: There's a chance that this post on Contextures might help: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/05/08/add-new-combobox-items-in-excel-userform/.  She was having a somewhat similar problem, and it was solved in the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why are you not using an 'ok' button to complete the action?

You should not bother users with messages while they are typing in a form.  Do it at the end.

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

    '// Validate form
    If txtAnswer.Text = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "You need to enter an answer!", vbExclamation, "No Answer Found!"
        txtAnswer.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '// You have reached here so form is correct carry on
    recordAnswer

End Sub
```

If you really want to use the behaviour you asked for then try this:

```
Private Sub txtAnswer_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Select Case KeyCode
    Case 13:
        If Me.txtAnswer.Value = "" Then
            temp = MsgBox("You need to enter an answer!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "No Answer Found!")              
            KeyCode = 0
        Else
            recordAnswer
        End If
    End Select

End Sub
```

The problem is that in your code you are setting focus but the enter key is firing afterwards.  You don't need to set focus because the textbox already has the focus you just need to cancel the enter key.

Comment: +1 Good Idea. You might want to add an `Exit Sub` after `txtAnswer.SetFocus`

Comment: Whoops, thanks @Sidd, feel free to edit my posts if you see me make stupid mistakes like that.

Comment: No. This is a math program for kids. The idea is that the student is cycling through basic math problems. There is one textbox on the form where they enter the answer to the problem posed. (e.g. 2 + 2 and they enter '4'). Upon entering their answer, they hit 'enter'. They are then told whether their answer is correct or not, but the form does not go away. A new problem is simply posed to them. They only hit the 'OK' button when they are finished answering questions and wish to see their results.

Comment: @Randy: Can we see your exel file if that is ok with you?

Comment: Then you need a 'Next Question' or 'Mark Question' button (which has the code above) as well as an 'ok' button. Actually the 'ok' button should probably be labeled 'Finished'. A lot of people would not expect a enter key to get them another question and may be left wondering what to do.  Anyway, it seems you have a bit of a mind set, so if you really want the behaviour you requested then see my edited answer

Comment: If you have ever done any data entry (which is what this essentially is), the last thing that you want to have to do is to reach for the mouse after you type in your entry. You just want to hit the 'enter' key since this is right on the same number pad. My 'OK' button doesn't say "OK", it says something entirely different. I'm leaving that out of this since these topics are outside of the scope of my question. Thanks for your help. I do appreciate it. Unfortunately, I implemented your suggestion and I still have the same behavior in this textbox. Oh well...

Comment: One more interesting development: I've traced the problem back to the launching of the message box. If I take that out, my code works just fine, although it doesn't give the user any feedback - it just denies the 'enter' key. Somehow, generating a message box takes the focus off of the textbox and I can't get it back there. Interesting...

Comment: Are you showing us the exact code you are using or are you posting a simplified or modified version. I only ask because I don't get the behaviour you do.  If you cannot post your workbook then could you post an screenshot of your form so we can try and reproduce the error.

Comment: This is the code. I took out a couple of comments that I had made to myself, but otherwise this is it.  Don't worry about this, though. In all of this debugging, I thought of a way to tell the user to enter something that doesn't involve a message box (and thus less intrusive, to your point, which I agree with). I'm just displaying a label with this message and then making it invisible once they enter a valid answer. I like that method much better, anyway.  Thanks again. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: The method you mention is actually very similar to what we use in .net now.  It's a control called the ErrorProvider control and it pops up an error symbol next to a textbox during validation when the user enters incorrect data.  Then when you hover over the symbol it tells you what is wrong with the entry.  Much less intrusive/interrupting than a msgbox.  Glad you have it sorted.

Comment: `You should not bother users with messages while they are typing in a form. Do it at the end.` +1

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem really complicated. I had a similar problem and really wanted a text warning. It seemed easier for me to just make an invisible label on the form that would show up if the input was incorrect. I also made the background of the label red so that the user would notice something was wrong. Doing it this way kept the cursor visible and right where they left off.

```
Public Function amount(ByRef cont As MSForms.TextBox) As Integer
'makes sure that a number is used
'could change to account for decimals if necessary
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
i = 0
If (cont.Value = "") Then Exit Function
    Do While i < 1000000
        If (cont.Value = i) Then
            UserForm1.Label257.Visible = False
            Exit Function
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
UserForm1.Label257.Visible = True
amount = 1
End Function

Public Sub qty_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If amount(UserForm1.qty) = 1 Then
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

I hope this helps other who run into this problem later on.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at the above code, I assume the i counter is to keep it going? Sorry a bit rusty, been a few years since I've done code.

At any rate, if thats the case you could always run it while i=0, do (or while true).

Sorry, first time posting here, hope that made sense.